# Only single series is shown

Tags: highmaps

I used an example from the demo on highcharts website, and the only modifications are:

- changed map to world.js
- Commented "allAreas" property

```js
$(function () {


    // Instanciate the map
    $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
        chart: {
            spacingBottom: 20
        },
        title : {
            text : 'Europe time zones'
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },

        plotOptions: {
            map: {
                //allAreas: false,
                joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: 'white',
                    formatter: function () {
                        if (this.point.properties && this.point.properties.labelrank.toString() < 5) {
                            return this.point.properties['iso-a2'];
                        }
                    },
                    format: null,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    }
                },
                mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '',
                    pointFormat: '{point.name}: <b>{series.name}</b>'
                }

            }
        },

        series : [{
            name: 'UTC',
            id: 'UTC',
            data: $.map(['IE', 'IS', 'GB', 'PT'], function (code) {
                return { code: code };
            })
        }, {
            name: 'UTC + 1',
            data: $.map(['NO', 'SE', 'DK', 'DE', 'NL', 'BE', 'LU', 'ES', 'FR', 'PL', 'CZ', 'AT', 'CH', 'LI', 'SK', 'HU',
                    'SI', 'IT', 'SM', 'HR', 'BA', 'YF', 'ME', 'AL', 'MK'], function (code) {
                return { code: code };
            })
        }, {
            name: 'UTC + 2',
            data: $.map(['FI', 'EE', 'LV', 'LT', 'BY', 'UA', 'MD', 'RO', 'BG', 'GR', 'TR', 'CY'], function (code) {
                return { code: code };
            })
        }, {
            name: 'UTC + 3',
            data: $.map(['RU'], function (code) {
                return { code: code };
            })
        }]
    });
});
```

Code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lvil/2bLfqxhs/)
Why only single series is visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line causing the issue is this: `//allAreas: false`.

This is the explanation and how to fix it **[(extract from the Highcharts support forum)](http://forum.highcharts.com/highmaps-usage-f14/category-map-issue-with-allareas-and-legend-t29942/)**

> According to the API, setting **`allAreas`** to **`true`** will render all of
>   the areas so also the one without value (as null value). Another
>   option is the **`nullColor`** which by default is a shade of grey and sets
>   the color to be used by null values.
>
> Therefore if you set **`allAreas`** to **`true`**, then each series will draw
>   all the areas and those with null values will be filled as grey (the
>   **`nullColor`**). Because the later series have a higher **`z-index`** these are
>   on top of the other series, resulting in a grey shape covering the
>   shapes beneath it.
>
> *If you want to set **`allAreas`** to **`true`** but still see through the
>   different series, you have to set the `nullColor` to transparent:*
>
> **`rgba(0,0,0,0)`**

**[Working JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2bLfqxhs/1/)**